# Creating a good looking interface for a Java CCG?

Tags: java, interface

I would like to create a Java collectible card game. I have the logic down pat, but I am having some trouble with the interface. I would like to make it look nice. Rather than using the standard java SWING components, I would like to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGxYg.jpg). What is necessary to create something like that?

Answer (score 2):

**Time and artistic skills**. No way around that. You can however, make it a little easier. You can use a library specifically designed for implementing GUIs.

Without knowing what you're using to render your game, I can only assume you haven't done any graphics yet. [Nifty GUI](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/) is one that comes to mind that is almost library agnostic. It uses OpenGL and Java but it works with more OpenGL libraries than most other GUI libraries, including: [jme](http://jmonkeyengine.com/), [jogl2](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), [lwjgl](http://www.lwjgl.org/) and it's own [custom renderer](http://nifty-gui.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=nifty-gui/nifty-renderer-test;a=tree;f=src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/renderer/test;h=394277417ffbbb67543c0411787dbfa06da4e17e;hb=HEAD).